# Ruby pass a parameter in to the constructor to behave like a dynamic method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my admin logs service I want to implement method which ignore specific data from hash which I receive (e.g. admin parameters like `email` `password` which are in form - `AdminUser.new(form)`). At this moment I know which parameters I want to ignore (these are permanent - `exclude_params` below)

```
  def exclude_params
    %w[
      reset_password_token
      sign_in_count
      created_at
      updated_at
    ]
  end
```

But I will use this service in many enpoints so I want to do more dynamically method that the call be like `LogAdminData.new(old_data: old_data, exclude_params: %i[encrypted_password nick_name]).call` in the same time I want to keep base ignored parameters (like the ones above - `created_at` `update_at` etc) of this method (so that would just be adding it to the existing array?). Sample of existing service below.

```
class LogAdminData
  def initialize(old_data:)
    @old_data = old_data.except(exclude_params)
  end

  def exclude_params
    %w[
      reset_password_token
      sign_in_count
      created_at
      updated_at
    ]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
class Foo

  attr_accessor :data

  EXCLUDED_PARAMS = %w(reset_password_token sign_in_count created_at updated_at)

  def initialize(data_hash, excluded_params = [])
    excluded_params += EXCLUDED_PARAMS
    @data = data_hash.reject{ |k, v| excluded_params.include? k }
  end

end
```

Be careful with keys of type Symbol as %w will render keys with string type.

Comment: What does `@data` ? your solution seems to be the most reasonable but I don't know why it doesn't work. If I set in `old_data` (in your example it is the same as `data_hash` something like `activities: 'sth'` and pass it to the excluded params in initializer - `excluded_params = %i[activities]` does not exclude him from `old_data` hash.

Comment: Ohh I've got it - the `EXCLUDED_PARAMS` shouldn't be a string but symbol

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the default value:

```
class LogAdminData

  DEFAULT_EXCLUDED_PARAMS = %i(reset_password_token sign_in_count created_at updated_at)

  def initialize(old_data:, excluded_params: [])
    all_excluded_params = excluded_params | DEFAULT_EXCLUDED_PARAMS
    @old_data = old_data.except(*all_excluded_params)
  end
end
```

Then use it like this:

```
LogAdminData.new(old_data: old_data, excluded_params: %i[encrypted_password nick_name])
```

or

```
LogAdminData.new(old_data: old_data)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! If I use it I'll receive ```undefined method `-' for #<Hash:0x00007fb6b81f3940>```

Answer (score 0):

Answers above can already solve your problem, but because you asked for

> Ruby pass a parameter in to the constructor to behave like a dynamic method

... a highly dynamic way of setting values (that would be independent per instance and per class), and that it's an interesting design concept to ponder about, that you could do something like the following which passes a proc as argument, and setting up defaults in initialization:

```
class LogAdminData
  attr_reader :old_data, :exclude_params

  DEFAULT_EXCLUDE_PARAMS = %w[
    reset_password_token
    sign_in_count
    created_at
    updated_at
  ].freeze

  def initialize(**args)
    @exclude_params = DEFAULT_EXCLUDE_PARAMS.clone

    args.each do |key, value|
      if value.is_a? Proc
        instance_variable_set(
          :"@#{key}",
          value.call(self, instance_variable_get(:"@#{key}"))
        )
      else
        instance_variable_set(:"@#{key}", value)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

#### Usage:

```
log_data = {
  'other_param1' => 'foo1',
  'other_param2' => 'foo2',
  'other_param3' => 'foo3',
  'created_at' => 'foo4',
  'updated_at' => 'foo5'
}

log_admin_data = LogAdminData.new(
  # order below matters: `exclude_params` arg should be before `old_data` arg
  # because each key-value pair gets set/evaluated to the instance variable
  exclude_params: -> (this, default) {
    # | merges two arrays and remove duplicates
    default | %w[other_param1 other_param2]
  },
  old_data: -> (this, default) {
    log_data.except(*this.exclude_params)
  }
)

puts log_admin_data.old_data
# => { 'other_param3' => 'foo3' }
puts log_admin_data.exclude_params
# => ["reset_password_token", "sign_in_count", "created_at", "updated_at", "other_param1", "other_param2"]
```

You can still pass values values just fine (non-proc):

```rb
log_admin_data = LogAdminData.new(
  exclude_params: %w[other_param1 other_param2],
  old_data: -> (this, default) {
    log_data.except(*this.exclude_params)
  }
)

puts log_admin_data.old_data
# => {"other_param3"=>"foo3", "created_at"=>"foo4", "updated_at"=>"foo5"}
puts log_admin_data.exclude_params
# => ['other_param1', 'other_param2']
```

*P.S. If you are implementing inheritance instead, i.e. `class LogAdminData < Base` instead of manually excluding defaults from your classes, then I can update my answer to suit your implementation.*